Issue with `defer` and `ng-content` in Angular 17
I am trying to render a defer block conditionally. This means that if a certain condition is met, the content will be deferred; otherwise, it should be rendered immediately. This needs to work both in regular rendering and in SSR (Server-Side Rendering), which defer does not support.
I need something like the following in my template:
<ng-template #someContent>  
   <div>Some content</div>
</ng-template>  
  
@if (condition) {  
  @defer (on viewport(info)) {  
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="someContent"/>  
  }  
} @else {  
  // instantly available also in SSR 
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="someContent"/>  
}

Desired Solution
This approach works, but I would like to have a wrapper component where I can inject the markup without writing the @if @else @defer logic at every position where I need it.
I have something like this in mind, but this solution does not work.
<conditionally-defer [condition]="condition">
   <div>Some content</div>
</conditionally-defer>

Wrapper Component Implementation
@Component({  
  selector: 'conditionally-defer',  
  standalone: true,  
  imports: [],  
  template: `  
      @defer (when condition) {  
        <ng-content/>      
        }  
      @if (!condition) {  
        <ng-content />
      }  
  `,  
  styles: `:host { display: block;}`  
})  
export class ConditionalDeferComponent {  
    condition = input.required();  
}

Possible Solution Using Templates
I am considering using Angular templates to achieve this. Here is my current idea:
<ng-template #template>
    <div>Some content</div>
</ng-template>
<conditionally-defer [condition]="condition" [template]="template"/>

... and using in "conditionally-defer" component like this:

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template" />


Maybe with a directive, could also work. Is there a more efficient or idiomatic approach to achieve this functionality in Angular?
Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

this is not possible. @defer bundle split logic piece is handled at the compile time and angular compiler should explicitly see what is deferred

The solution using a wrapper component that receives templates as input has sufficed for our use case. I'm not sure if this solution might lead to performance issues. One problem we are encountering is view encapsulation for styling, which is usually defined in the parent component. Therefore, it only works with components that do not rely on the parent component's styling. Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution that pertains to directives.
This is the defer wrapper component:
import { Component, input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgTemplateOutlet } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'conditionally-defer',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgTemplateOutlet],
  template: `
    @defer (when condition()) {
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template()" />
    }
    @if (!condition()) {
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template()" />
    }
  `,
})
export class ConditionalDeferComponent {
  condition = input.required<boolean>();
  template = input.required<TemplateRef<any>>();
}


using it like this:
<ng-template #t1>
    <div>Template One: Deferred Content</div>
</ng-template>
<conditionally-defer [condition]="lazyUI" [template]="t1" />
<ng-template #t2>
    <div>Template Two: Immediate Content</div>
</ng-template>
<conditionally-defer [condition]="lazyUI" [template]="t2" />

